# laravel passport return data with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, passport.js

I need to return message but I get an error.

**My controller:**

```
    $user = User::findOrFail($id) ;
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    $user->role_id = $request->input('role_id');
    if($user->update()){
        return new UserResource($user);       
    }
```

**I tried:**

```
        return new UserResource($user)->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
```

Comment: And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ';'

Comment: the error happen when i use         return new UserResource($user)->with('status', 'Profile updated!');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place the creation of the `UserResource` instance between brackets so php knows you are using the `with` function on this new instance.

```
return (new UserResource($user))->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
```

Comment: get empty array []

Comment: I have no idea what `UserResource` is. If this solved your current syntax error, please mark this as the answer to your question and create a new question for the data problem.